# business trip to Amsterdam for 3 days , would like to extend the trip as a tourist to Paris

Tags: schengen-visas, tourist-visas, business-travel

I am going on a business trip to Amsterdam for 3 days , would like to extend the trip as a tourist to Paris for 6 days. Which countries consulate should I apply. What should I mention in the cover letter of Schengen visa?

Comment: @David I don’t think the visa has been issued yet, the OP is asking where to apply to and what to put in the cover letter. Sounds like a typical Schengen application question to me.

Comment: @Traveller Yes, on re-read, I agree with you. I'll delete my comment.

Comment: @David: That's not a good duplicate target, because its only answer completely ignores the "main purpose" criterion for identifying a main destination, which seems to be governing in this case.

Comment: You're right. I'm not accurate today. Thanks for the correction.

Comment: My maximum number of stay is in Paris. But my first port of entry is Netherlands. Should I apply visa in France consulate or Netherlands. Purpose is tourism